# Extract array values with last extraction memory on callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, extract

Let's say I have a dynamic array that is populated on page load with various amounts of strings inside:

```
var arr = ["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10","string11","string12","string13","string14","string15","string16","string17","string18"];
```

I then have a function that is called on each event (let's say a click) that needs to bring back 3 strings of the array consecutively while remembering which value it left off at, the last time it was called. So:

First time function is called, it returns:

```
string1, string2, string3
```

Second time it is called, it returns:

```
string4, string5, string6
```

and so on...

I don't the need the code for the click event or the callback function, rather the code for the function that would generate the extraction each time and bring it back. Something simple like being able to call:

```
arr.runExtraction();
```

on each callback and having it bring back the desired data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should happen if the array is exhausted? Start from the beginning?

You could do something like this:

```
function get_iterator(values, steps, start) {
    steps = steps || 1;
    var current = start || 0,
        max = values.length;
    return function() {
        var end = current+steps,
            end = end > max ? max : end,
            t = values.slice(current, end);
        current = end % max;
        // or if you don't want to wrap around:
        // current = end; 
        return t;
    }
}
```

*Edit: Added `start` parameter.*

As `current` will be the same as `values.length` in the end, `splice` will return an empty array if you don't wrap around.

Using `slice` won't change the original array.

And then

```
var extract = get_iterator(arr, 3);
var arr1 = extract(); // gives you the first three elements
var arr2 = extract(); // gives you the next three elements etc.
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/8sJux/)

It might give you less elements in the "last" extraction if the number of elements is not divisible by number of extracted elements. The next call will let it start from the beginning again. You could also modify it that it wraps around and takes elements from the beginning so that it will always return as many elements as you have specified.

**Reference**: [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: oops, forgot to add that part. If the extraction reaches the end of the array and it cannot pull three items because only 2(or 1) are left, it should pull those 2(or 1) and stop completely. Thanks for the response looking at it now.

Comment: @Jim: Updated my answer. If you don't want to wrap around anyway, and you don't care whether array is changed or not, then `splice` seems to be the easier way.

Comment: You are the man! Thanks, didn't think it would be hard. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10","string11","string12","string13","string14","string15","string16","string17","string18"];

var runExtraction = function () {
  return arr.splice(0, 3);
}
```